# Codeigniter REST API giving unknown method?

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

I'm using https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver with codeigniter.
I'm trying to add a resource, and enable a get method with an id.
I added the Users controller which inherits the REST_Controller. I added a few methods, index_get, index_post. They both worked perfectly.

I then attempted to add an id parameter to the index_get function (so you can access a particular user- eg `localhost/proj/Users/4` would you give you the user with id 4)

```
class Users extends REST_Controller {

    public function index_get($id) {
        echo $id;
    }

    public function index_post() {
       echo "post";
    }

}
```

I then tried, using postman, to access this get method:
`localhost/proj/index.php/users/3` but it responded with:

> {   "status": false,   "error": "Unknown method" }

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 5):

According to [CodeIgniter Rest Server doc](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver/blob/master/README.md#handling-requests), you can access request parameter as below :

```
$this->get('blah'); // GET param 
$this->post('blah'); // POST param 
$this->put('blah'); // PUT param
```

So, Users class should be like that ..

```
class Api extends REST_Controller {

    public function user_get() {
        echo $this->get('id');
    }

    public function user_post() {
       echo $this->post('id');
    }
}
```

When you test with postman, you can request as below :

For get method,

```
http://localhost/proj/api/user?id=3
http://localhost/proj/api/user/id/3
```

For post method,

```
http://localhost/proj/api/user
form-data : [id : 2]
```

Hope, it will be useful for you.

Comment: Alright, but I learnt online that accessing the resource should be done with /users/(:id),,, it makes no sense to me that this isn't possible with the REST api, as it IS possible with the vanilla codeigniter. Isn't there some way I can define a route or something?

Comment: @maor10 The problem is method name in your controller. When you use `index_get` as your method name, the library assume the url as `http://localhost/proj/index.php/users/index`. That's why when you call `http://localhost/proj/index.php/users/` with GET method, `index_get` is triggered automatically. So, try to change class name and method name to get more meaningful url. I've updated my answer. Please check it again !

Answer (score 0):

I've such trouble and this solution worked for me.

For example, you have a controller file called Api.php like this:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

use chriskacerguis\RestServer\RestController;

class Api extends RestController {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

function user_get($id) {
    echo $id;
}

function user_put() {

}

function user_post() {

}

function user_delete() {

}
}

/* End of file Api.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/Api.php */
```

On the browser, you don't need to write http://localhost/api/user_get/1, instead, http://localhost/api/user/1, where 1 is [:id,] because the word **_get**, **_put**, **_post**, or **_delete** after the word **user** is the method. So, if you're using the get method, you should write your function in a class like this eg. user_get, users_get, students_get, etc.

Hope it can solve your issue.