# I get " {"status":false,"error":"Unknown method"} " error when i try to post anything in my codeigniter restful Api?

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter, api

```
class Login extends Api{

    public function index_post()
    {
        $name = $this->post("username");
        $result = "Hello $name";
        $this->Output($result);
    }

    public function load_get()
    {
        echo "blablabla";
    }
}
```

And yes i have removed `_post` from method name when i use it in url. So help me guys

Comment: You are using wrong methdod. try this :  `$name = $this->input->post("username");`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643133/codeigniter-rest-api-giving-unknown-method

Comment: Can you post Api Controller code here

Comment: @prakashtank i know that, but thats not the issue. I still cant post request in Api.

Comment: @ChrisChen bro i saw that post, plus every post in here but none solve this  issue, they only tell us to not use _post in our url. Still the same error

Comment: No i cant, actually i am trying to get data via Angular2 front end, its not working @FairyDancer

Comment: @mezzanine I am actually refering to "class Users extends REST_Controller"  should you try "class Login extends REST_Controller" instead?

Comment: No thats not the issue because i am extending a function inside REST_Controller that extends that class. @ChrisChen I think i am confusing you. Sorry